# popup_closed_by_user google login issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

I am trying to implement `Google Login` functionality in `ReactJS`.
In `index.html`, I have added:
`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>`

React Code is given below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
const YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID =
    "252545854785-kjhkjhkhkhkhkjhjkhkjhkjhkjhjkhkk.apps.googleusercontent.com"; //FAKE

const GoogleLoginButton = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const initGoogleSignIn = () => {
            window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
                window.gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                });
            });
        };

        // Check if Google Sign-In API library is already loaded
        if (!window.gapi) {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';
            script.onload = initGoogleSignIn;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        } else {
            initGoogleSignIn();
        }
    }, []);

    const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
        // Trigger the Google Sign-In process
        window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then((googleUser) => {
            const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            const idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

            // Handle the response from Google login
            window.console.log('googleUser, profile, idToken--(handleGoogleLogin-SUCCESS)', googleUser, profile, idToken);
            // console.log(profile);
            // console.log(idToken);
        }).catch((error) => {
            window.console.log('--(handleGoogleLogin-FAILED)', error);
        });
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={handleGoogleLogin}>
            Login with Google
        </button>
    );
};

export default GoogleLoginButton;
```

But I am getting an error : `{"error": "popup_closed_by_user"}` in console. Whereas, I didn't close the popup. The popup was automatically closed.

#### Note

I have tested incognito mode.
I have tested in both Chrome and Firefox but getting same error.
I have tried to use `react-google-login` library, but getting the same error.